# how to access values in python from json

Tags: python-2.7, loops

I'm new to Python but required to write a script for API so trying to read the response from API and put it in a file, version is python2.7

Following is the code

```
import requests 
import json
#URL = "someurl"
# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
#response = requests.get(url = URL) 

#print(response.status_code)
#print(response.content)
items = json.loads('{"batch_id":"5d83a2d317cb4","names": 
           {"19202":"text1","19203":"text2"}}')
print(items['names'])
for item in items['names']:
     print(item)
```

Current output is 
19202
19203

But I would like to pick text1,text2 and write to a file, can anyone help how to get those values

Answer (score 0):

items is a dictionary. `items['names']` is also a dictionary. `for item in items['names']:` will iterate over keys not values. The `item` will hold key in the dictionary.

To access the value in that key-value pair, you have to use `print items['names'][item]` instead of `print item`. Your code should look something like below.

```
import requests 
import json
#URL = "someurl"
# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
#response = requests.get(url = URL) 

#print(response.status_code)
#print(response.content)
items = json.loads('{"batch_id":"5d83a2d317cb4","names": 
           {"19202":"text1","19203":"text2"}}')
print(items['names'])
for item in items['names']:
     print(items['names'][item])
```

Comment: that does not seem to work, it gives error "print(items[item])KeyError: u'19202'" but i have resolved with print(items['names'][item])

Comment: Oh my bad, it has to be `items['names'][item]`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print(list(items['names'].values()))
['text1', 'text2']
```

So you can do like this:

```py
for item in items['names'].values():
    print(item)
```